# What does value "-inf" mean after multiplication of two double in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, double

I'm doing some calculus on double numbers with 17 numbers after the decimal point.
like 0.1256478965842365987 * 0.125639874569874563
and I get the value named "-inf" when I display it in the console.

What is the signification of that?

Comment: are those the **exact** numbers you used, can you print them out?

Comment: Post the actual code giving you this result.

Comment: absolutely post the code, yes!

Comment: It means either you have a very badly broken system, or, more likely, it resulted from a different calculation from the one you think you did.

Comment: these aren't the decimals you're looking for...

Answer (score 2):

It means minus infinity.

> EEE 754 floating point numbers can represent positive or negative infinity, and 
>   NaN (not a number).  These three values arise from calculations whose result is 
>   undefined or cannot be represented accurately. You can also deliberately set a 
>   floating-point variable to any of them, which is sometimes useful. Some examples 
>   of calculations that produce infinity or NaN:

Now, it is strange that you got that multiplying those two numbers.